# Access class property inside class method

Tags: php, class, properties

I have a simple PHP class, I'm trying to access a property of that class from a method in that class. I've tried the $this->property_name syntax and that doesn't appear to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
class NavigationBuilder {

    public $mPage;
    public $mGeoID;
    public $mContinent;
    public $mCountry;
    public $mRegion;

    private $Geograph = 'a';

    public function construct_navigation() {

    }

    public function __construct() {

        var_dump($Geograph);
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try `var_dump($this->Geograph);`

Comment: `$this->propertyName` is the way to do it. Could you show the code where it wasn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that you need to use `$this->property`.
Your example works if you use `$this`

```
<?php

class NavigationBuilder {

    public $mPage;
    public $mGeoID;
    public $mContinent;
    public $mCountry;
    public $mRegion;

    private $Geograph = 'a';

    public function construct_navigation() {

    }

    public function __construct() {

        var_dump($this->Geograph);
    }
}

// prints string(1) "a"
$geo = new NavigationBuilder();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class NavigationBuilder {

    public $mPage;
    public $mGeoID;
    public $mContinent;
    public $mCountry;
    public $mRegion;

    private $Geograph;

    public function construct_navigation() {
      $this->Geograph = 'a';
    }

    public function __construct() {

        var_dump($this->Geograph);
    }

}
```